How to quantize a pretrained model using tensorflow lite?
I have been trying to use a pretrained model from tensorflow.keras library - which is MobileNet
If I try to quantize it using
tfmot.quantization.keras.quantize_model(base_model)

It gives me an error stating - "to_quantize" can only either be a keras Sequential or Functional model.
I have tried using the example on the official docs but that doesn't work either. Link -
https://www.tensorflow.org/model_optimization/guide/quantization/training_example
Thanks in advance for helping out!.....:)

You need to show the complete code that fails. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

For detailed information: -
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78601256/how-to-quantize-a-pretrained-model-e-g-mobilenet

In the future, please edit your question to include new information, instead of opening a new question.

wait, we can also edit our posted questions? news to me! but alright! advice taken. Thanks. Could you please answer my question, it literally itches my brain!
