How to quantize a pretrained model (e.g. MobileNet)
I am using tensorflow lite framework in order to create a quantized model for an experiment. I want to deploy this model on my Raspberry Pi but it seems that using a pretrained model for quantizing doesn't work.
I tried executing below code on Colab and Kaggle notebook.

from tensorflow.keras.applications import MobileNet

pretrained_model = MobileNet(include_top=False, weights='imagenet',input_shape=(32,32,3))

import tensorflow_model_optimization as tfmot

pretrained_model.trainable = True

q_pretrained_model = tfmot.quantization.keras.quantize_
model(pretrained_model)

and it throws an error: -
to_quantize can only either be a keras Sequential or Functional model.

Not sure why this is tagged [quantization-aware-training] because it appears that MobileNet was't trained using quantization-aware training.

Yeah I know but I'd like to perform quantization-aware-training on this model. So........ could you help me out here please!
